# ftp client connects OK, login OK, but a 'list' command returns: Unable to build data connection: No route to host

Tags: networking, debian, ftp

I am trying to set up an FTP server on a Debian host (11.8).  I'm using proftpd as my server.  I can connect from the server host to the server (ie both server and client on the same host) successfully so configuration is good.  When I try to connect from a second host (also runninng Debian 11.8) the connection and login succeed but any action that involves a data transfer fails with the mentioned error.  Note that both hosts are internal, same network, this is not an attempt to access a server from the Internet.

Searching the web has found multiple cases with several different suggested fixes, including using passive mode (no change), change "net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse" to 0, loading kernel modules "ip_nat_ftp" or "nf_nat_ftp".  I have set the configuration file for proftpd to use the PassivePorts directive and opened the ports on both hosts.  None of these fix the problem.

I can ssh from each host to the other so I believe all network related configs are good.

Any ideas on how to figure out the cause and fix to this?

Thanks.

Additional info:  stopping the firewall on both server and client allowed ftp to work, in both active and passive modes.  Starting the firewall on the server did not affect this, so it would seem the problem is the firewall on the client stopping the return connection from the server.  I just learned how to whitelist an IP address in firewalld and tried that on the client side after restarting the firewall.  No joy, when active the firewall stops access from the server.  As noted in the first part of this, I also tried to set ProFTPd to use a particular range of addresses for passive connections (PassivePorts 49152 49162) and setting the firewall on the client to open these ports.  Running nmap on the server against the client shows ports 49152-49162 as "closed", which I think means they could be used?  But transfers still fail.  Note, ALL transfers fail - put, get, ls, ... fail to transfer data.

Update:  ftp transfers are now working.  It could be a matter of my not getting passive mode set correctly.  But I also discovered that the proftpd package was not properly configured and fixed that as well.

Currently I have proftpd set to use a specific range of ports for passive transfers and the client firewall set to allow that range of ports **and** whitelist the IP of the server.  Technically I should not need both, but since it is working I don't think I'll mess with the settings.

Answer (score 0):

This is to line out the solution step by step:

ProFTPd is the server, configured to use the PassivePorts directive.

The firewall on the server is configured to allow FTP on port 21.

The firewall on the **client** is configured to whitelist the IP of the server **and** to allow the same set of ports that proftpd uses in the PassivePorts setting.  Both these are probably not required but I have not yet tried reconfiguring.

The ftp command run on the client must be run in passive mode.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).